# Disable popup in webbrowser-control

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

In my form, when i click webbrowser1, many window IE advertising opened.

I used my code:

```
webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Have a look at [WebBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.scripterrorssuppressed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) seems you haven't implemented the event

Answer (score 7):

You can use this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e90ef09e-1fc2-4e7c-b433-d004ded6d6ae/how-to-block-pop-up-with-webbrowser-control)

If here pop up means WebBrowser open a webpage in a new Internet Explorer, then please follow these steps to avoid such condition:

1. Click WebBrowser in Windows Form design time, and open property window of WebBrowser.
2. Add NewWindow event handler at Event tab of property window.
3. Use these codes in the event handler, like:

   `private void webBrowser1_NewWindow(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) {
         webBrowser1.Navigate(webBrowser1.StatusText);
          e.Cancel = true;
      }`

Here, StatusText actually holds the URL of the target webpage original opened in Internet Explorer.   Besides, e.Cancel = ture is to cancel the original action to open webpage in Internet Explorer.